# Know from where the call has been made into the server - Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is there a way to, server-side, know that an access to the server is being made by an specific Adobe Air app?

I want to deliver some stuff to the app, but I want to be sure that I will deliver to the right app, not anyone hacking and recompiling it.

I think the best way would be to expose to the server the certificate used to sign the app. But how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with The_asMan's comment.  But if you want, you could load the file:

app:/meta-inf/signatures.xml

That will get you the hash of the swf.  Unfortunately, this is useless, cause anyone could just inject that into the urlrequest.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I know that it is not a safe method. I am just making more and more hard to hack.

Answer (score 3):

All security needs to be done on the server side of things.
Anything done on the client side can and probably will be hacked.
One method you could do is have the server track sessions.
Another would be to encrypt the data back and forth from the server.

Relying on where the app originated is not reliable since all that info can be spoofed.

Have the app log in to the server.

Comment: Thanks asMan. Could you point me infos about the server track sessions?